# Finding Eduroam WiFi Certifications

Tags: wifi

I need certificate to connect to WiFi. If I visit webpage where I can download certificate I can easily install it, but I have downloaded wrong certificate. I

t seems impossible to find certificates anywhere in settings or Internet Explorer?

I need certificates for well known wifi system Eduroam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no option to remove certificates. The only way to fix this is resetting your phone. settings -> about -> reset your phone

There is a feature request posted [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679225/provide-a-way-to-remove-certificates-from-windows-phone-7) asking to provide a way to remove certificates so Microsoft knows about the issue. The only other option is to wait until they implement it but guess that is not an option.